# CSS3 and JS: Rotation on click per 90° to a full circle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

probably a simple question but … I don't know.

```
<a href="#" id="line">|</a>​
```

I toggle a class `active` when clicking on a link that rotates `#line` by 90°. If the class is removed again the `#line` rotates back to 0°.

I wonder how I can make it rotate within a full circle?

So I click it the first time it rotates to the right to 90°. If I click it again It rotates back (to the left) to 0°. However I want it to rotate to to the right again till it reaches 180°. And so forth. So it should rotate within a full circle.

http://jsfiddle.net/5mCTd/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple, see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5mCTd/19/).

```
var angle = 90;    

$('#line').click(function() {
    $(this).css ({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
           '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
             '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
    });
    angle+=90;
});​
```

I've commented out the CSS & JS that is not required.
Do let me know if that's not the effect you're looking for.
Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way: do it with JavaScript. Increase the rotation amount by 90 each time and set the element's inline style to the new rotation amount.

The biggest problem is that theoretically you want it to go from 270 to 360 not 0. So just setting four classes (0, 90, 180, 270, ... uh ... 0) isn't going to help.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part here (thanks to Anthony Mills for pointing it out) is the transition from 270 to 360 -- you cannot simply return to 0, you have to go to 360, 450, etc. Therefore, we need to take the current angle and always add 90 to it.

Trying to get the current angle from the `transform` property and add 90 to it isn't worth it for this, since the transform is stored as a matrix by the browser and you'd have to reverse engineer the angle from the matrix (not *very* difficult and there are scripts out there to do it, but why bother?)

Instead, I'm going to use N, E, W, S (North, East, West, and South) to indicate state, just so you know where the letters are coming from. Default will be N, so...

```
<a href="#" id="line" class="N" data-turns="0">|</a>
```

And then a bit of jQuery. I use the class to figure out the current angle, so I don't have to reverse the matrix from `transform`.

```
$('#line').click(function() {
    var rot = 360 * $(this).attr('data-turns');
    switch ($(this).attr('class'))
    {
        case 'N':
            rot += 0;
            $(this).removeClass('N').addClass('E');
            break;
        case 'E':
            rot += 90;
            $(this).removeClass('E').addClass('S');
            break;
        case 'S':
            rot += 180;
            $(this).removeClass('S').addClass('W');
            break;
        case 'W':
            rot += 360;
            $(this).attr('data-turns', $(this).attr('data-turns') + 1);
            $(this).removeClass('W').addClass('N');
            break;
        default:
            $(this).attr('class', 'N');
    }
    $(this).css('transform', 'rotate('+rot+'deg)');
});
```

Note that this only works if you aren't using any classes on `#line`. If you are, you'll have to use `if`/`else if`/`else` with `hasClass()` instead of `switch` with `attr('class')`. Really, there are probably better fields to use than class for storing this information (the HTML5 `data-` fields, for example); I just used class because it was quicker/easier to write the CSS and jQuery.

EDIT: Added `N2` for the `360deg` option so rotation completes. Not 100% sure if the `N2` to `E` transition will rotate as desired. Thanks to Anthony Mills for mentioning this.

EDIT2: Removed CSS styling altogether, switched to calculating the correct rotation based on the class and a particular `data-` field, namely `data-turns`.

Comment: Pretty sure that if he does this then the W to N transition will animate through a 270-degree arc from 270 to 0, not a 90-degree arc from 270 to 360.

Comment: @AnthonyMills Yeah, I just noticed that in your answer; editing now. You're probably right, though I haven't tested this personally.

Comment: Sorry, the N2 to E transition will just do the 270-degree arc from 360 to 90 now. :) Sadly, there is no way to do this just with classes unless you do some crazy thing where once you get to 360 you swap out the class for something that doesn't do the transition at all, then add a class with the transition stuff resetting the rotation to 0. (That way you don't have it animating all around as it goes to 0.)

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion when I thought about what would happen if that were, in fact, the case. Very sad. Editing again, gonna do a hybrid approach.